# Call COM/COM+ objects from TIBCO BisinessWorks process

Tags: com, com+, tibco, businessworks

Can anyone describe the ways to call COM/COM+ objects from TIBCO BisinessWorks process, please. I cannot find such activities in my palette.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To communicate with COM objects from BusinessWorks, you need a BusinessWorks Adapter.  Your can find information on the COM Adapter here: https://docs.tibco.com/products/tibco-adapter-for-com-5-3-1

The adapter is sold separately and not included in the basic BusinessWorks installation (separate licensing might be required).

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it is using a Java-Com Bridge like http://sourceforge.net/projects/jcom/
You might invoke it from BusinessWorks in a Java Activity.

You might evaluate cost of the adapter vs. effort of doing it "by hand" with a lib like this.